# How to do paging in a grid with a ArrayStore

Tags: extjs, paging

I have a grid which it's store is an ArrayStore, I need load the the data manually:

```
var result = [];
result.push(obj);
...
Ext.getCmp('uploadWindow').down('grid').getStore().loadData(result);
```

how to add paging in this grid, really appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

I find the answer, use PagingMemoryProxy:

```
var store = Ext.getCmp('uploadWindow').down('grid').getStore();
store.setProxy({
   type: 'pagingmemory',
   data: result
});
store.load();
```

Answer (score 0):

As I know - [PagingMemoryProxy](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.ux.data.PagingMemoryProxy) is used to optimize a huge data showing in the grid.
And what you need - just to use [loadData method](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-loadData) to load data to the store.